# How to get the distance between a well and the edge of the screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

For my web page I want to place something in between the edge of a well I made with Bootstrap and the edge of the screen. Is there a way to do that so that it stays there, even on resize?

Comment: If i understood you correctly you want to fix the position of the element. That's means that the page will not be responsive. So why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want the element between the screen and the well to be responsive of that distance as well.

Comment: That's totally different to what you said first in the problem description. You can use column offsets to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the offset css classes `.col-md-offset-*` is an example. More at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do that, even on resize.

Comment: Do you mean, is not? You're sentence is strangely worded, which is why I ask.